# Secure way to send information from Java to database?

Tags: java, database, security

I need a secure way to send information from a Java application to a database for my website. I currently have a PHP page on the server that accepts the parameters posted from a URLConnection in Java, and then updates the database. My fear is that, if somebody decompiles it, they can see the exact URL and parameters. I am new to this type of development, so I don't know a better/safer way to do it.

What is a better or safer way to get the data to the database?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give the application access to the database then you can never 100% prevent any application simulating the behaviour of your application from having the same access. period. You can only make your pattern harder to be found.

Better is letting your server (in this case your php-document) validate each and every input it gets so that bad behaviour is excluded. Let the php generate querys and let the client-application only send the data needed like username, password or other information. in your php, you have to be prepared, that everything could be send, not only data you expect. Use prepared statements to prevent sql-injections and use regex to sanitise any input given.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you're afraid that someone will find out from your code url, username and password and connect to the database with these parameters. You can prevent that misbehaviour on network layer (i.e. allowing only your IP address to access the database by configuring firewall) or, if you cannot alter firewall/router configuration then change the database configuration. For example, PostgreSQL has a file pg_hba.conf where you can specify list of IP addresses that are allowed to access. However, you must prevent other vulnerabilites like SQL injection that use your connection to the database.

Answer (score 1):

From the sounds it, your using a Java program to connect to your PHP/server. If your worried about the security of the connection, you could establish a SSL connection using HTTPS (example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-https-client-httpsurlconnection-example/))

You could also establish a challenge/response protocol, where the server requests some kind of key from the client, this could use a rolling series of public/private keys with the message encrypted with these to further reduce the chance of a false input request